# Warning: the 'flutter' tool you are currently running is not the one from the current directory

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Running Flutter doctor produces a warning.

**Warning: the 'flutter' tool you are currently running is not the one from the
current directory:**

**running Flutter: /home/franklin/flutter/flutter**

**current directory: /home/franklin/flutter**

**This can happen when you have multiple copies of the flutter installed. Please check
your system path to verify that you're running the expected version (run
'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your path).**

But I don't have multiple copies of flutter installed. What else causes this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your flutter **sdk path**. You need to setup a correct  flutter sdk path to access it from all terminal sessions.

Your flutter git directory is this > /home/franklin/flutter/flutter

The **path** you setup and the **path** to the directory should be same. Or else it will throw error

**Following are the steps for updating/creating flutter path:**

1) Determine the directory where you placed the Flutter SDK.

2) Open bashrc file (use vim or nano, for eg: vim  /home/user/.bashrc).

3) Add the following line to your bashrc file ()

```
 export PATH="[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin:$PATH"
```

4) Save the changes and you are done

Comment: yes it was my mistake. I had accidently created a flutter folder and i had placed the flutter sdk inside it. So it was an issue of the path. @vishnu s pillai

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio:
Menu > File > Settings... > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > Flutter SDK path: (change your path: /home/franklin/flutter)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by removing pubspec.lock and running `flutter packages get`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this warning in the Windows environment by changing the reference on the .package file as indicated by the warning message.  Just make sure all your references point to the correct location of your flutter directory.

Answer (score 0):

The path you setup and directory path must be identical and case sensitive. I had setup /Users/Myusername/dev/flutter while the actual path was /Users/Myusername/Dev/flutter. The "D" in Dev was in actual path while on the setup path, I had set it to non caps "d".